# Boost converter Issue

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, boost

My aim is to boost a 3v DC input voltage to an output DC voltage of around 12 to 15v. Based on the schematic I have designed this should work theoretically with the components I have chosen. Right now it seems as though the circuit isn't doing much at all, I believe the issue lies with the MOSFET I have chosen - perhaps the voltage at the gate is too low? currently I am feeding a square wave input at 1MHz, 5v amplitude through to the gate. Can anyone spot the issue based on the schematic?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What does the datasheet say you need as \$V_{GS}\$ ?

Comment: As an absolute maximum of (+/- 20v)

Comment: VGS(th) is Min 2v and Max 4v

Comment: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/IRF520A.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry but obviously you don't have't a clue what you're doing.  Designing isn't about slapping some components together and hoping it works. If you want to do this, educate yourself first. There are plenty of books on the subject. If you don't then just buy a ready-to-use module from ebay.

Comment: Turn the frequency down to 1khz and see what happens.  1MHz switching power supplies may not be exactly state of the art, but they're definitely the advanced end of things.

Answer (score 4):

Bad design alert: -

- 1N4001 diode will never work at 1MHz - the reverse recovery time is several microseconds from memory (just checked, it's 30 us)
- A 1mH inductor (never mind the ludicrously high 100 mH inductor) will never get enough energy at 1MHz: -

3V across 1mH develops a current of \$\dfrac{3V\times 0.5us}{1mH}\$ = 1.5mA.

That's an energy storage of 1.125 nJ and at 1 MHz will be a power of 1.125 nJ*1MHz = 1.125 mW.

All that power flows into the resistor (10 ohm) and generates a voltage above the 3V rail of 107 mV i.e. the output will be 3.1 volts. It's going to be virtually 3V out with a 100 mH inductor - try 1 uH.

With 1uH, the current will ramp to 1.5 amps in 0.5 us. This is an energy storage of 1.125 uJ and a power of 1.125 watts or about 3.3 volts added the standing 3V and that assumes a perfect diode.

Comment: The op's inductor is 100mH (now, maybe it was different when you wrote this)

Comment: @WillDean thanks will, it makes the analysis even worse.

Comment: Why run 1 MHZ ? Why use IRF520 ? Why use electro on output at ! MHz?

Answer (score 3):

Thaitan, Start by looking at how the inductor works: The Volts x time in the switch-on time should be equal to Volts x time during the switch off time. If you do the math for a 3V to 15.7V you get 81% duty cycle, not a square wave that you show. 1MHz may be unnecessarily high. I would suggest 200kHz so that the on-time is about 4us or so. Typically, the inductor ripple would be somewhere like 1/2 to 1/4 of the output current. For For your 1.5A output try 0.5A ripple. This determines your inductor value: L=3Vx4us/500mA = 24uH. The 1mH you show is way too large. The 1N4001 diode can not handle 1.5Amps, and the pulses through that diode will be 5 times the steady state 1.5A or, about 7.5Amp. Find a 20A diode.